# Merge two DataTable's data into a single DataTable withour using loops etc.?

Tags: asp.net, performance, datatable

I have two different `DataTable`s, `dt1` and `dt2`. Both of the `DataTable`s have the same structure, but contain different data.

I want to store the data from `dt1` and `dt2` in `dt1`.

I'm currently doing it using a for-loop by adding a single row to `dt1` in each iteration, but it takes too much time.

Is there any faster/direct way to do this?

Comment: There's possibly direct ways to do what you are asking, but without knowing what your data looks like, we have **no** idea where to start. Maybe show some of your current code, or even the tables layout.

Comment: i don't know why peoples vote down here for standard questions also. just want to misuse there privileges.

Comment: Stackoverflow is a Q & A site which doesn't mean it will answer all repeated questions. Most probably, the question might be a repetition.

Comment: @SubinJacob then you should provide a link which shows that it is a repeated question. Voting down is not a solution, if he can't find answer on google.

Comment: @CodeRider I didn't vote down. Also, He wasn't asking about this question, he was asking generally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, once i tried the same.

I think there is a `merge` method of `datatable`. by using this you can `merge` the dt2's data in dt1.

but the condition is that both of `datatables` should follow the same table structure and `datatypes` of each `column` should be same.

you can use it like below:

```
     dt1.Merge(dt2);
```

let me know, it works for you or not?